# How do I select each data set from a Row_Number Over Partition by table based on the Row_Number Over Partition by column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I select each data set from a Row_Number Over Partition by table based on the Row_Number Over Partition by column?

please diagram below:

```
+-----------+-------------+-------------------+------------+----------+
| packageid | packagename | package max units | references | row_Numb |
+-----------+-------------+-------------------+------------+----------+
|     44    | Basic       | 10                | 103        | 1        |
|     45    | Basic       | 10                | 103        | 2        |
|     42    | Cola        | 10                | 102        | 1        |
|     43    | Cola        | 10                | 102        | 2        |
|     46    | Cola        | 10                | 102        | 3        |
|     2     | Home        | 11                | 101        | 1        |
|     11    | Home        | 11                | 101        | 2        |
|     21    | Home        | 11                | 101        | 3        |
|     1     | Spicy       | 11                | 104        | 1        |
|     3     | Spicy       | 11                | 104        | 2        |
|     41    | Spicy       | 11                | 104        | 3        |
+-----------+-------------+-------------------+------------+----------+
```

I want select each data set in each group based on the row_num column.

Every attempt is welcomed.

Comment: I've got no idea what you are asking, can you please add some explanation and desired result?

Comment: Post your expected result

Answer (score 2):

Although it sounds like you already have the `ROW_NUMBER()` column, I believe it is what you are asking for . For the first record for each `PACKAGENAME` use:

```
 SELECT s.* FROM (
     SELECT t.*,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.packagename ORDER BY t.packageid) as rnk
     FROM YourTable t) s
WHERE s.rnk = 1
```

For all of them use only the inner query.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the `cte` version, if you want to fetch single record from each group.

```
  ;with cte_1
   as(
     SELECT *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [packagename],[package max units],  [references] ORDER BY [packageid]) as row_Numb 
     FROM YourTable ) 
   SELECT [packageid],[packagename],[package max units],[reference] 
   FROM cte_1
   WHERE row_Numb  = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use TOP 1 WITH TIES with ordering by ROW_NUMBER():

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES *
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY packagename ORDER BY packageid)
```

Output:

```
packageid   packagename package max units   references
44          Basic       10                  103
42          Cola        10                  102
2           Home        11                  101
1           Spicy       11                  104
```